# I could not install Wine due to EULA message

Tags: wine, software-installation

I was trying to install Picasa on Ubuntu 12.04 and first had to install Wine which came up with a EULA that I could not see how to agree to.

When trying to install Picasa from the terminal I got the following message:

```
ian@ian-Dimension-8100:~$ wine ~/picasa39-setup.exe
The program 'wine' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install wine1.4-i386
ian@ian-Dimension-8100:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.4-i386
[sudo] password for ian: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

How to I overcome this problem? The following are the instructions I was following:

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or search terminal in Dash,then install *wine* and *winetricks* using below command

   `sudo apt-get install wine winetricks`
2. Download Picasa 3.9 from Google use below command

   `cd ~/ && wget http://dl.google.com/picasa/picasa39-setup.exe`
3. Install Picasa 3.9 via wine use below command

   `wine ~/picasa39-setup.exe`
4. Install IE6 via winetricks

   `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine sh winetricks -q ie6`
5. *Done, you launch Picasa 3.9 by searching picasa in Dash now*

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how the EULA was presented to you?

Comment: Hit the tab key when you get there.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate the cursor with the tab key in console and 'click' buttons with space or enter.

So you basically hit the tab-key to get to the accept Button and then you hit enter.